# Cannot POST a multipart/form-data using Fetch TYPESCRIPT

Tags: typescript, request, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to fetch this code bellow, im starting using fetch so im having some issues

```
import fetch, { Headers, RequestInit } from "node-fetch";
import FormData = require("form-data");

const exampleFile = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "../lib/dummy.pdf"));
  const myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

const form = new FormData();
  form.append("file", exampleFile);

const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: form,
    redirect: "follow"
  };

await fetch(`https://api.mercadolibre.com/messages/attachments?access_token=${accessToken}`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response)
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
```

but this responses this JSON (it should be just an Id for the attachment from MercadoLibre):

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _transformState: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/messages/attachments?access_token=#######',
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: From

    .then(response => response)

To

    .then(response => response.json())


But since your response status is 400, the server is also not expecting your request format. 

(source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

Comment: @MoK yeah, i mean, i would like to know whats wrong with the request format.
Thanks for the .json() part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: I was able to fix it by excluding the Content-Type property, allowing to fetch  to detect and set the boundary and content type automatically.

The new code:

```
const exampleFile = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "../lib/dummy.pdf"));

const form = new FormData();
form.append("file", exampleFile);

const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: "POST",
    body: form
  };

await fetch(`https://api.mercadolibre.com/messages/attachments?access_token=${accessToken}`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
```