# Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob' when formData.append(...) for file upload

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, multipartform-data, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension that needs to upload selected file via multipart formdata.

I found some snippets, like [Cannot POST a multipart/form-data using Fetch TYPESCRIPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782060/cannot-post-a-multipart-form-data-using-fetch-typescript), and wrote something similar:

```
        window.showOpenDialog({
            canSelectFiles: true,
            canSelectFolders: false,
            canSelectMany: false,
            filters: {
                'image': ['jpg', 'png'],
            },
            title: 'Add Image',
        }).then(async uriList => {
            if (undefined === uriList || uriList.length === 0) {
                return;
            }

            let imageFile = createReadStream(uriList[0].fsPath);

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', imageFile); // <- ts(2345) error
        });
```

However it complains:

```
Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Type 'ReadStream' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': size, type, arrayBuffer, slice, and 2 more.ts(2345)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try putting an `import FormData from "form-data";` and see if it helps.

Comment: When I pass this FormData type to fetch, I get "Type 'FormData' is not assignable to type 'BodyInit | null | undefined'.". Can you add explaination why would this work?

Comment: where will you be executing this, nodejs or browser ?? I am assuming `browser`.

Comment: can you share what does `createReadStream` do? I mean the function implementation?

Comment: `BodyInit` is also a `ReadableStream`, but got to know the return type of `createReadStream`..

Comment: [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams).

Comment: Type of `type BodyInit = Blob | BufferSource | FormData | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream | string;`

Comment: If `createReadStream` returns a `FormData` then it should be of type `FormData` as defined in `lib.dom.d.ts`.

Comment: so.. details of `createReadStream` function is going to really help here.. and if you can arrange please?

Comment: @NalinRanjan - Thanks for spending time on this question. `createReadStream` is imported from `fs` came natively with the VSCode extension development environment. It does not return `FormData`, it returns a `ReadStream` of specified filepath.

Comment: will it be possible to return any of `Blob | BufferSource | FormData | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream | string` from `createReadStream` function?

Comment: As far as I know it only returns ReadStream. But I could be wrong since I am very new to TypeScript and JavaScript.

Comment: `fs`, the package that you are using, can you share the source of it plz? Is it the `nodejs` package?

Comment: Is [this](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatereadstreamoptions) the method?

Comment: Is it possible to use [readFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options) function instead. It should help producing a `Blob`, which then we should be able to use in `BodyInit`...

Comment: If possible, can you also share some more info so that I can try a scenario on my end... That way this could be little quicker and I should be able to produce an answer for you..

Comment: @NalinRanjan - thanks so much for your time again. I tried stepping into the `createReadStream` method in debugger, and it says the `fs` module is actually `\<node_internals>\fs.js`.

Comment: At high-level, I am trying to build a VSCode extension that allows uploading file via multipart/form-data. You could easily setup a boilterplate project by following https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension. I don't mind any other approach as long as it works. Thanks!

Comment: @NalinRanjan - as for the `readFile` method, it returns a `Buffer` type which is accepted by `FormData.append()`. Thanks for pointing that out. However, my concern is the file could be large, say 500mb or more. Is it still a best practice to use `readFile` to read entire file in this case?

Comment: You can read a file in chunks if it's a large one. There are options available to read in such a fashion. Try to explore the api of `fs`. And let us know if you run into another problem doing it that way.

Answer (score 9):

As @Nalin Ranjan mentioned in comment, using

`import FormData from "form-data";`

Fixed the problem.